# When searching Issues or Pull Requests in Github, can you specify a date relative to "today"?

Tags: github, pull-request

**Is there a way to search Pull Requests (and likewise Issues) on Github where you specify a date range relative to today?**

My team meets weekly with another team, and we like to present them a list of Github pull requests we've merged within the past week.

We can do a search for any items merged since a particular date with the filter:

`is:pr is:closed merged:>=2016-03-31`

But this needs to be updated every week, which is less than ideal. (As you can see, it's already out of date :)

However I see no mention of relative dates in their support article on searching issues:
https://help.github.com/articles/searching-issues/

Nor is there mention of relative dates in the search syntax article:
https://help.github.com/articles/search-syntax/

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?  I am running into a similar issue.

Comment: @HPJAJ Sadly, no. According to the docs, it still does not appear to be available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not aware of a way to do this and as you mention their search documentation does not cover it.

However, the [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#response) does provide a `created_at` and an `updated_at` property for issues it returns, so depending on how useful it would be you might consider setting up a simple script to get all the issues related to specific repos and then filtering the response(s) you get back based on those properties.

Answer (score 8):

The search API may have been updated since this original question, but you can limit date ranges by duplicating the exclude params.

```
-created:<=2018-01-01 -created:>=2018-03-31 {other params...}
```

If you only want anything newer than 2018, then you can leave out the first part, e.g.:

```
-created:>=2018 {other params...}
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a JS snippet that you can use in the `URL` section of a Chrome bookmark (haven't tested other browsers) that will dynamically set the `created_at` greater than filter to the date 14 days before the current date:

```
javascript:void(numDays = 14, d = new Date(),d.setDate(d.getDate() - numDays),day = ('0' + d.getDate()).slice(-2),month = ('0' + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2),year = d.getFullYear(),targetWin = window.open(`https://github.com/github/codeql/pulls?q=is%3Apr+is%3Aopen+created%3A>${year}-${month}-${day}`, %27_self%27))
```

Notes:

- Make sure you update the url to match the repo you are querying on (it's currently set to the `https://github.com/github/codeql` repo)
- You can adjust the `numDays` variable to the relative difference you want